# How to pass VARGRAPHIC to Stored procedures in DB2?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, ibm-data-studio

How can I call a sp with VARGRAPHIC variable type as input?
I've create this super simple sp that dose nothing and just for test, with following statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE (IN VARNAME vargraphic(5) )
LANGUAGE SQL
P1: BEGIN

END P1
```

but when I call the sp in IBM Data Studio,it raises this error:

```
{? = call SCHEMA.MYPROCEDURE (?)}
[SQL0189] Coded Character Set Identifier 37 not valid.
Run of routine failed.
 - Roll back completed successfully.
```

is there any problem in my sp code?
should I define CCSIDs? How and where?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you would want to specify the CCSID of your parameter like this

```
call SCHEMA.MYPROCEDURE( CAST(? AS VARGRAPHIC(5) CCSID 65535) )
```

picking the correct CCSID number as appropriate

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcast.htm